# Passing the selected object id to the @HTML.Action parameter

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Once again, I added an post, this time corrected, because the previous one was difficult to understand

I have a page where directories are shown something like a network drive

Here is the main Action to render view with catalogs:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{

    return View(_context.NodeEntities.Where(x=>x.ParentId == id));
}
```

This action renders the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Tree.Models.Node>

@{

    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var node in Model)
        {
            <div class="col-md-3 one-node mx-3" id="@node.Id" onClick="Select(this.id)">
                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/144/000000/folder-invoices.png">
                @Html.ActionLink(node.Name, "Index", "Home", new { node.Id }, new { @style = "display:block;" })

            </div>
        }
    </div>


    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button id="change_name" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
        Change name
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Change name:</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div id="modalBodyId" class="modal-body">

                    @Html.Action("EditName", "Home", new { id = 1 })
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<script>
    var div;
    function Select(clicked_id) {

        if (div != null) {
            div.style.removeProperty('background-color');
        }
        div = document.getElementById(clicked_id);
        div.style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
    }
</script>
```

I would like to do something such that when a user clicks on a given folder, he is shown the option rename. After clicking change name, a pop-up appears in which the user can change the name of the selected folder. And what I wrote about it is done, but not completely. For me, it works so that when you click just change the name, a pop-up window appears and @HtmlAction is launched in the "modal-body":

```
public PartialViewResult EditName(int id)
{
    Node node = _context.NodeEntities.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

    return PartialView("_EditName", node); 
}
```

Here is the PartialView:

```
@model Tree.Models.Node



@using (Html.BeginForm("ZmienNazwe", "Home"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
    </div>
}
```

It works, but I passed in @Html.Action parameter "id = 3" and I would like to put there the id of the selected folder

[Screen showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dneef.png)

Comment: you can't use `@Html.Action` for this because razor code is executed from the server

Comment: I thought so, but how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `Html.Action` for this. It will execute ounce when the page loads, but you cannot update the route values dynamically client-side and have `Html.Action` execute again to fetch the new partial view. You would have to reload the whole page, and pass `Html.Action` the new value.

To do what you want you first have to add a custom click event to your "Change name" button that fetches the correct partial view, then displays the modal.

First remove `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter"` from you button so that Bootstrap doesn't wire up a click event to the button since we are creating our own.

```
<button id="change_name" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
    Change name
</button>
```

Next write some javascript to wire up your own click event to this button:

```
       $('#change_name').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var id = 1; // TODO: Get id of selected node

            $.get('/path/to/EditName/' + id, function (html) {
                $('#exampleModalCenter .modal-body').html(html);
                $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');
            });
        });
```

**UPDATE**

Most times I like to have my url generation on the server-side instead of having a string somewhere in javascript file or view.
To do this I will geneate my url with `@Url.Action` on the button.

On a `button` you can do this:

```
<button id="change_name" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-base-url="@Url.Action("EditName", "Controller")">
    Change name
</button>
```

And javascript update:

```
var url = $(this).data('base-url');
$.get(url  + '/' + id, function (html) {
```

**Or** simply use an `<a>` tag (instead of a `button`) and href attribute:

```
<a id="change_name" href="@Url.Action("EditName", "Controller")" class="btn btn-primary">
        Change name
    </a>
```

And javascript updates:

```
$.get(this.href+ '/' + id, function (html) {
```

Comment: @KrystianWolański I made some updates for better url's